# material style animations over an image button

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, material-design, android-imagebutton

I am attempting to create a calculator app, I would like to use this [material design animation](https://youtu.be/RwAupmFbVyA) when the user puts their finger on a button. How would I add that animation to an image button?

Thanks!

Comment: The video is private?

Comment: @azizbekian just changed it to unlisted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Ripple effect outside ImageButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393648/implementing-ripple-effect-outside-imagebutton)

Comment: @azizbekian that post dosen't explain how to create/obtain the animation.