# How to make ripple of MaterialButton borderless

Tags: android, material-design, ripple

I am using a `MaterialButton` and I need it to have a borderless ripple effect.

I have tried setting borderless ripple with  `android:background="attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"` but no luck. Looks like `MaterialButton` has its background and ripple separated.
I have inspected the sources and I see ripple drawable is set up within  the MaterialButtonHelper class. I was not able to override `rippleDrawable` through the MaterialButton.

Is there any way to use a MaterialButton with borderless ripple?

Comment: Have you tried using `app:rippleColor="@color/colorPrimary"`

Comment: Hey check this out, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27393648/implementing-ripple-effect-outside-imagebutton?